# Effect of trifluoromethyl substituent on electrophilic substitution

Tags: organic-chemistry, electrophilic-substitution

Problem -

> Find which carbon is most susceptible to electrophilic attack (among carbons numbered $1$ to $6$):
> [image]

Answer given (may not be the correct one) -

> $2$

#### My question -

$1.$ I know that $\ce{-CCl3}$ group exerts a negative hyperconjugation effect, hence acting as a deactivating and *meta*-directing group. If $\ce{-CF3}$ has a similar effect (which dominates over $\mathrm{-I}$ effect), then in that case phenyl ring **D** will be more electron-rich as compared to ring **B** - since the ring **B**, being attached at *para* of the main ring **A**, will participate in resonance due to the negative hyperconjugation of $\ce{-CF3}$ group. Since resonance does not result in a positive charge at the *meta* carbon of ring **A**, so I feel ring **C** should be more susceptible to electrophile. Within ring **C**, I expect only inductive effect to operate, so the carbon farthest from ring **A** will be richest in electrons. Accordingly my answer in this case will be $5$.

$2.$ If $\ce{-CF3}$ does **not** exert negative hyperconjugation - then in that case, only inductive effect will decide the electron density and consequently the carbon farthest from $\ce{-CF3}$ group will be most electron-rich. My answer in this case will be $6$.

In either case, I don't see how $2$ can be the answer. Is the answer key wrong? If yes, then which of my two reasonings is correct? If no, then what am I missing?

Comment: @Ashish Ahuja - it does, it's the same question from the same test paper!

Comment: If you don't mind, can you tell me whether, the paper mentioned is for mains or adv?

Comment: @Rishi Advanced - and their answer key to this one was wrong btw, the correct answer is 4.